# (FM Build) No fracture tab?

Tags: add-on

I am trying out the Fracture Modifier build for the first time, everything is working just fine, except I don't have a fracture tab!?!?!

Any idea why?

My screen below:

[image]

Tutorial Screen below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess after downloading the FM build you also need to download the helper addon.

http://blenderphysics.com/fracturemodifier/

This solved my problem.